# Is drinking blended meals just as nutritious as eating whole meals?

Tags: nutrition

If you cook a meal and then blend it and drink it, are you getting more-or-less the same amount of nutrition from the meal? Does your body absorb the nutrients in the same way as it would otherwise?

It seems like since food turns into sludge in your stomach anyway and the blender acts as a proxy for mechanical digestion, there wouldn't be a huge difference.

Is there any research on this?

Comment: I’m closing this question because questions about diet and nutrition are off topic unless directly related to medical treatments.

Comment: I strongly suspect your intuition is correct. Your teeth do the same thing a blender does, just not as finely.